# Autoupdaters for .NET and alternatives to wyBuild/wyUpdate?

Tags: c#, .net, auto-update

I am searching for alternatives to autoupdating our software. Not [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) and nor in the line of [wyBuild and wyUpdate](http://wyday.com/wybuild/).

Comment: Out of interest, what's wrong with "wy"?

Comment: To me, 'wy' is still the best out there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try these:

- [AutoUpdate+](http://www.autoupdateplus.com/)  [This one seems to have disappeared]
- [IncUpdate](http://www.sunisoft.com/incupdate)
- [Advanced Installer Updater](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/auto-updater.html)
- [Sharp AutoUpdater](http://csautoupdater.sourceforge.net/)
- [AutoUpdate](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Auto_Update_Revisited.aspx)
- [AutoUpdater.NET](http://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET)
- [NetSparkle](http://github.com/dei79/netsparkle)
- [WyBuild](http://wyday.com/wybuild/)  [Included here for completeness--though OP wanted alternatives]

I use IncUpdate.  It doesn't seem to be being updated anymore--but it continues to meet my needs (I released an update with it today).

Comment: This is very, very old, but I'm having trouble finding any up-to-date information on recommended auto-update products. (One of your links is broken, and several are somewhat obsolete or reference products that seem to be abandoned.) If this question was asked today, what would your recommendation(s) be? Thanks.

Comment: I ran across this question right after I'd done a rather extensive search to find a product that would meet my needs for this.  I ended up with IncUpdate and I continue to use it to update my .NET Winforms applications today.  IncUpdate itself hasn't received any attention since 2010 though, but it continues to work for what I need it for.   If I had the budget, I'd probably go with Advanced Installer.  They have a complete system that includes a good updater--but it's pretty spendy.  Some good open source options down the list on GitHub now that look to be being maintained.

Comment: UPDATE (apologies for the pun): I'm using Advanced Installer Updater now--mostly for it's ability to do service based updates without requiring Admin Rights (after the initial install).

Answer (score 4):

I know it doesn't quite meet your requiremenets but maybe take a look at [Omaha](https://github.com/google/omaha) (used for google update), to quote:

> Omaha is the open-source version of Google Update, a program to
>   install requested software and keep it up to date. The Google-branded
>   version of Omaha is used to support software patching (both background
>   updating, and on-demand update checks) for Google Chrome, Earth, and a
>   variety of other Google products on Windows.
>
> We know that keeping software updated is both important and hard, and
>   so by open-sourcing this project, our hope is that perhaps we can help
>   others solve this problem. So, if you'd like to get involved, or even
>   use Omaha to support your own software projects, then just follow the
>   instructions in the Developer Setup Guide, and you'll be good to go!

Comment: Omaha is too much for my requirements -- I need a more streamlined solution, thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Check [NetSparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/)