# How to implement an Autoupdate background check using .NET technologies?

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce, software-update

I used ClickOnce and its has nice APIs for deploying and implementing background software checks.

The problem that I have with ClickOnce is that I need to install multiple instances of my App and clickonce does not support this.

Is there another solution for deploying and doing a software update background check that I can implement into my app?  like how google chrome or firefox do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have to install multiple instances? Try to address that and use ClickOnce.

Comment: This app uses the serial port and does some data management with its raw data.  Its easier to install different instances with their own configurations.

Comment: For anyone looking into this question.  I ran into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130765/software-auto-update and led me into this project call [NetSparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com).  Haven't tried it yet but looks like it is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can install multiple instances of the same application.

Frankly, if the only difference is the configuration, I would prompt the user to select a configuration before starting up the app, and have it use the selected config. Unless he needs to have more than one running simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you.  Your solution is nice but I can't see it working for this app.  It'll be ok if the deployments are small like 2 deployments (in your demo).  2 deployments are manageable.  But having 16 com ports would mean 16 deployments it can get messy.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AutoUpdater.NET](http://autoupdaterdotnet.codeplex.com/) class library for .net created by me. You just need to add One line of code in each instance and you can update your application with multiple instances easily.